# How to output data to different columns in CSV using Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activeadmin

I'm using Active Admin CSV export to export my users from the ddbb.

It works, but, It will only create 1 column for each record and will separate the attributes by ',' instead of creating a new column for each attribute:

```
38,2014-06-11 21:31:53 UTC,jaime@gmail.com,Jaime L.
```

I would like it to add each attribute to a different column.
Is this possible?

I'm currently doing:

```
  csv do
    column :id
    column :created_at
    column :email
    column(:name) { |user| user.name }
  end
```

in my resource (user)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use TAB separator (\t) instead of comma (,). So, just specify it:

```
csv col_sep: "\t" do
  ...
```

[Here](http://activeadmin.info/docs/4-csv-format.html) is detail information about `csv` options.

Comment: Hello @maxd thanks for the response.

It partially helped, but still the results are not shown on separate columns.

It will show like this

2014-06-08 18:03:59 UTC user@test.com     username

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, so with your code:

```
csv force_quotes: true, col_sep: ';', column_names: true do
    column :id
    column :created_at
    column :email
    column(:name) { |user| user.name }
end
```

I know I'm not using the tab seperator '\t', but it work.

GL